# Ruby on Rails devise ユーザープロフィールについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Ruby on Rails を使用し、ウェブアプリの開発に挑戦しています。

deviseの実装や独自のカラム(名前、年齢、自己紹介など)の設定など行いました。

今困っていることとしては、

年齢、名前、自己紹介などを表示するマイページの作成と
ユーザーが自分でプロフィールの編集を行えるようにすることの２点です。

色々なサイトを探してみたものの、プロフィール編集後のルーティングに関する記事が多く、その前のステップの記事がなかなか見つかりませんでした。
さらに検索する中でdevise用のコントローラーなどにハマってしまい、、、

もしかすると簡単な質問をしているのかもしれませんが、自分にとってものすごい課題です
どなたか教えてください！

必要があればソースコードも全て用意いたします。

Comment: Rails自体の学習は行われましたか？Railsはweb開発の知識があっても最初に覚えるべき内容が多くあります。まずはRailsTutorialなどをこなすことをオススメします。 https://railstutorial.jp/ ←はRails5.1版ですが、他のversion用のtutorialもあるので、ご自分の環境にあったtutorialを行って見てください。ただ、古いtutorialだとgem周りでハマりそうな気がします。。。

Answer (score 0):

「ユーザー」のモデルを編集するためのビューとコントローラが必要です。

手っ取り早いのは、別のrailsアプリを作ってそこで

```
rails g scaffold user name なんとかかんとか
```

して、生成されたファイルをコピーしてくる方法です。このとき、モデルとマイグレーションをコピーしないよう注意してください。